# Flutter and CupertinoContext menu with avatar after press and hold is showing the white squere

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino, cupertino-widgets

after pressing and holding the avatar I am seeing the white squere around it, can you help me solve this problem, thank you. I tried mby everything, but it didnt work at all. I cannot find any other question of this type, so I am mby dumb and its simple solution, here is the three images of the process showing that it is happening only when the avtar is pressed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APzzi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iozDF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4I57.png)

```
import 'package:countee/components/my_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SettingsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SettingsPage> createState() => _SettingsPageState();
}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Container(

        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: MyCard(
          theHeight: 600.0,
          theWidth: 325.0,
          theChild: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [

                    Center(
                      child: CupertinoContextMenu(

                        actions: [
                          CupertinoContextMenuAction(
                              trailingIcon: CupertinoIcons
                                  .arrow_2_circlepath_circle_fill,
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: const Text("Změnit")),
                          CupertinoContextMenuAction(
                              isDestructiveAction: true,
                              trailingIcon: CupertinoIcons.delete,
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: const Text(
                                "Odtranit",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              )),
                        ],
                        child: const CircleAvatar(

                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          radius: 60,
                          backgroundImage:

                              AssetImage("assets/images/avatar.jpg"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    const Text(
                      "Jan",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "Černohous",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the white container around your avatar go away after you press on something else afterward?

Comment: Yes, its only around the avatar while tapping on it or press and hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CupertinoContextMenu.builder` to have more control over ui.

```dart
CupertinoContextMenu.builder(
  actions: [
    //  ...
  ],
  builder: (context, animation) {
    return const CircleAvatar(
      radius: 60,
      backgroundImage:
          AssetImage("assets/images/avatar.jpg"),
    );
  },
),
```